# How can I extract a portion of a structured data file

Tags: text-processing, awk

I want to extract all lines in section `["$AccountWide"] =`  between `["rules"] =`  and `},` into a file. But my script does not stop at `},` as intended. I put this code together from different sources.

```
awk '/["$AccountWide"]/ {s=1};   # set the flag s to 1 when ["$AccountWide"] is found
    (s==1 && /["rules"]/) {p=1}; # set the flag p to 1 when s1=1 and ["rules"] is found
    (p==1 && /},/) {s=0};        # set the flag s to 0 when p=1 and }, is found
    (p==1 && s==1) p' x          # if p=1 and S=1 I want print
```

The data file looks like this:

```
    {
            ["$AccountWide"] = 
            {
                ["rules"] = 
                {
                    ["is learnable by Aerithrìa"] = "type(\"motif\", \"recipe\")\nand needlearn(\"Aerithrìa\")",
                    ["#Launder"] = "false",
                    ["#BagtoHomeBank"] = "countBank(\">\", 0)",
                    ["test"] = "(not rule(\"is protected\"))\nand not fcoismarker(constant(\"FCO ignore\"))\n-- and not fcoismarker(constant(\"FCO Quest Item\"))\nand (\n\t\ttype(\"Masterwrit\") and not rule(\"$pricelimit4Writs\")\n\t)",
                },
                ["ruleSets"] =
```

Comment: Welcome to the site. It would appear that you are working with structured data. In that case, using line-oriented tools like `awk` is discouraged; you may want to look into a dedicated parser for that file format instead.

Comment: Yeah, this will be a nightmare to parse with something like `awk` or regular expressions: you have escaped quotations, structures spanning multiple lines, arbitrarily deeply nested dictionary-alike structures. What software produced this? Maybe they have a parser which you could instrumentalize?

Comment: The data file is a simple table structure created with lua. I've searched the web for many days to find a Lua to CSV parser that meets my needs. But I couldn't find anything that works with MacOS. The separation is only the first part. Then I need to convert the extracted part into something that is easy to maintain. In fact, the contents of these extracted strings are structured Lua expressions. Finally I want to assemble all the stuff back into a single file.

p.s. I know, from behind through the chest in the eye

Comment: If you wrote the Lua code, it ought to be easier to fix it so that it outputs a parsable output document in a better know format, such as YAML, JSON, TOML, CSV, or even HCL or XML.  There are shell parsers for all these formats that could be used without having to invent a new one.

Answer (score 1):

Using any awk:

```
$ awk '
    /\["\$AccountWide"]/  { state=1 }
    state && /\["rules"]/ { state=2 }
    state == 2            { print }
    /},/                  { state=0 }
' file

                ["rules"] =
                {
                    ["is learnable by Aerithrìa"] = "type(\"motif\", \"recipe\")\nand needlearn(\"Aerithrìa\")",
                    ["#Launder"] = "false",
                    ["#BagtoHomeBank"] = "countBank(\">\", 0)",
                    ["test"] = "(not rule(\"is protected\"))\nand not fcoismarker(constant(\"FCO ignore\"))\n-- and not fcoismarker(constant(\"FCO Quest Item\"))\nand (\n\t\ttype(\"Masterwrit\") and not rule(\"$pricelimit4Writs\")\n\t)",
                },
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, in general I agree with the *AdminBee*. I do not know, why did you intended the use of `awk` . If you definitely must use it, look at the awk manual for the way how to use its internal variables RS (Record Separator), and FS (Field Separator). You may experiment to set these vars to RS="\[\"rules\"\]" (yes, the separator can be set to string) and FS="\{|\}" (yes, the separator can be set to either "{" or "}"). Then the requester portion of text can be specified as $2.

So the `awk` command can look like:

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS="\[\"rules\"\]";FS="\{|\}"}{print $2}' data.txt
```

It could be good practise to show longer sample of text, not only the text that match, but the wrong text, too.

Comment: Thanks, I will have a look at this and yes I also had a look to the awk manual. 
Its' only 555 pages, maybe one day i'll do the Prof. Dr. Dr. awk

Comment: Please, if you find some answer to be solving your question, do not forget to mark the post as **Answered**.

Comment: You should mention that requires an awk version that accepts multi-char RS such as GNU awk. It won't work in a POSIX awk. Also `RS="\[\"rules\"\]";FS="\{|\}"` can be written without so many escapes as `RS="\[\"rules\"]";FS="[{}]"`

Comment: @EdMorton Definitely right, I work on linux with `gawk`.  It does not work on MacOS X -Darwin. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem myself:

1. After some time I found out that MacOS uses an outdated awk
2. I worked on this script based on a manual for the original awk with no extensions
3. First I checked every single pattern until it worked
4. then I put the script back together - and it works :)

```
awk '/\[\"\$AccountWide\"]/ {s=1} 
                (s==1 && /\[\"rules\"\]/) {p=1}
                (p==1 && /\}\,/) {s=0} 
                (p==1 && s==1) {print}' x
```

Comment: That awk script and the one in your question would each behave the same way in any awk, whatever problem you were having had nothing to do with awk version. When you wrote `/\[\"\$AccountWide\"]/` you knew you didn't have to escape `]` but by the next line `/\[\"rules\"\]/` you forgot again. You don't have to escape `}` or `,` in `/\}\,/` - just `/},/` would work. You also don't have to escape any of the `"`s.